# MariaDB: Select average per month per item (Pivot table)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have MariaDB table that looks like this:

| Component | Timestamp | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Component one | 2021-10-01 14:04:54 | 40 |
| Component one | 2021-11-01 14:04:45 | 10 |
| Component one | 2021-11-11 11:05:23 | 20 |
| Component one | 2021-12-01 13:04:43 | 20 |
| Component one | 2021-12-12 12:14:11 | 30 |
| Component two | 2021-11-01 14:04:27 | 45 |
| Component two | 2021-12-01 13:04:08 | 23 |

What I'd like to do is show the average duration of each component over the last three months. It should look something like this :

| Component | AVG Duration (October) | AVG Duration (November) | AVG Duration (December) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Component one | 40 | 15 | 25 |
| Component two |  | 45 | 23 |

I tried messing around with a pivot table I found online, but the below query still results in multiple lines (1 for each month, with the other months empty on that line)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('(IF(MONTHNAME(s.LOG_TIMESTAMP) = "', MONTHNAME(`LOG_TIMESTAMP`),'", AVG(`DURATION`),"")) AS ',MONTHNAME(LOG_TIMESTAMP) )
              ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.COMPONENT,  ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM table1 s
                 GROUP BY s.COMPONENT, MONTHNAME(s.LOG_TIMESTAMP)
                 ORDER BY s.COMPONENT');
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

So if I run that query the output for component 1 (for example) is like this :

| Component | AVG Duration (October) | AVG Duration (November) | AVG Duration (December) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Component one | 40 |  |  |
| Component one |  | 15 |  |
| Component one |  |  | 25 |

It's probably the group-by expression having the log_timestamp, but if I remove that one the concat function just writes the average duration (of all months) in the first available month. I don't have any experience with pivotting tables so I'm a bit out of my depth here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a final query like this:

```
SELECT Component,
       MAX(IF(mth=10,avgd,0)) AS 'October',
       MAX(IF(mth=11,avgd,0)) AS 'November',
       MAX(IF(mth=12,avgd,0)) AS 'December'
 FROM
(SELECT Component,
       MONTH(LOG_TIMESTAMP) mth,
       AVG(Duration) Avgd
FROM table1
GROUP BY Component, mth) v
GROUP BY Component;
```

And prepared statement syntax of the following:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT Component,',
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
       MAX(IF(mth=',mth,',avgd,0)) AS "',mthname,'"') 
       SEPARATOR ','),
       '
FROM (SELECT Component,
       MONTH(LOG_TIMESTAMP) mth,
       AVG(Duration) Avgd
FROM table1
GROUP BY Component, mth) v
GROUP BY Component') INTO @sql
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(LOG_TIMESTAMP) mth, 
       MONTHNAME(LOG_TIMESTAMP) mthname
FROM table1) a;

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=498a1ff4d52a312a140562ac8b442c7d)

Comment: That's perfect! Seems to be exactly what I need. I just have two questions if you're willing to answer;

1. Let's say I have results of december 2021 but also from december 2020. Does MAX make sure that I always get the latest results? I want to prevent using an explicit year so I don't have to change my query each year

2. Is the difference between the prepared statement and the final query that in the final query I get averages of all three months (regardless of data) and with the prepared statement I only get months where atleast 1 component has data? Was that the intended effect?

Comment: Well, the `MAX()` is actually just there to get the `avgd` value from the subquery. On which year it will take, the current query will take everything correspond to the month defined regardless of any year. If your condition only for the current year, then you should add a `WHERE YEAR(LOG_TIMESTAMP)=YEAR(NOW())` in the subquery to make sure of that. [See this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f966c6c709dbb64c1fd614d8b631b803).

Comment: I think for your second question, I'm guessing you mean that whether or not a component have data, you still want to return them. Let's say the there are two tables, one is the component table and the other is a log table. Then what you can do is a `LEFT JOIN` on them and return every existing component regardless of data. Something [like in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=eef5b950c3da1ec256a53ab2cefb02be) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in 2 steps:

1. Write a query to compute the averages.
2. Write a query to pivot, using the step-1 query in a 'derived table'.